# prevent use of token created by an other web api project

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, access-token, antiforgerytoken

Hi to all of stack fans.
I have a question about web API token.
how can i prevent access to web API controllers that has [authorize] 
by token that created by an other web API project?
i created two separate  web API project.then i got a token from first web API
project after that i used that token to access second web API project.i successfully accessed to controllers of second project by token that created with first web API project.i want to prevent access to second web API controllers by first project created token.what should i do?